# primefaces datatable on dialog does not show in first time

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

I'm using primefaces-3.4 and have a dialog (detail page) to be shown details of the selected item on datatable on master page. my bean is @ViewScoped and at actionListener method I'm loading details for sure. When the master page displayed, at first click on p:commandButton, it does not fill the dialog where at second click it displays correctly. I've checked using Chrome developer tools, and see nothing anormal, it's just details of the selected item is not getting "bind" to UI.

here is my bean code and xhtml

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    // load credits if there is an account selected...
    if (mainBean.getSelectedAccount() != null) {

        ArrayList<Credit> cs = loadCredits(mainBean.getSelectedAccount());
        setCredits(cs);
        mainBean.getSelectedAccount().setCredits(cs);
    }
    if (this.selectedCredit != null) {
        ArrayList<Installation> installations = loadInstallations(selectedCredit);
        selectedCredit.setInstallations(installations);
        setPaymentAmount(Float.parseFloat(installations.get(installations.size()-1).getAmount()));
    }
}
....
//actionListener to select
public String select() {
    if (selectedCredit != null) {
        ArrayList<Installation> installations = loadInstallations(selectedCredit);
        selectedCredit.setInstallations(installations);
    }
    return null;
}
```

and here is snippets in my xhtml

```
<p:dataTable var="credit" selectionMode="single"
                        emptyMessage="Kayıt Bulunamadı..."
                        selection="#{accountBean.selectedCredit}" rowKey="#{credit.id}"
                        value="#{accountBean.credits}" id="credit_table" paginator="true"
                        paginatorAlwaysVisible="false" rows="10">
                        <f:facet name="header">
                            <small>İlgili krediyi seçtikten sonra "Detay" butonuna
                                tıklayınız..</small>
                        </f:facet>
                        <p:column>
                            <h:outputText headerText="Kredi ID" value="#{credit.id}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Kredi Adı">
                            <h:outputText value="#{credit.name}" />
                        </p:column>
                        <p:column headerText="Tutarı">
                            <h:outputText value="#{credit.total}" />
                        </p:column>

                        <f:facet name="footer">
                            <p:toolbar>
                                <p:toolbarGroup align="left">
                                    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{accountBean.select}"
                                        icon="ui-icon-search"
                                        update=":productdetailform:product_detail"
                                        oncomplete="kredidetail.show();" value="Detay">
                                        <f:ajax render=":productdetailform:product_detail" />
                                    </p:commandButton>
....
<h:form id="productdetailform">
            <p:dialog id="product_detail"
                header="#{accountBean.selectedCredit.name}" widgetVar="kredidetail"
                modal="true" height="700" width="850">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="twelve columns">
                        <ul class="block-grid three-up">
                            <li><b>Kredi Hesap Adı: </b> <h:inputText readonly="true"
                                    value="#{accountBean.selectedCredit.name}" /></li>
                            <li><b>Kredi Tutarı: </b> <h:inputText readonly="true"
                                    value="#{accountBean.selectedCredit.total}" /></li>
                            <li><b>Veriliş Tarihi: </b> <p:calendar readonly="true"
                                    pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" readonlyInput="true" id="loan_date"
                                    value="#{accountBean.selectedCredit.loanDate}" /></li>
                            <li><b>Ödenen: </b> <h:inputText readonly="true"
                                    value="#{accountBean.selectedCredit.paid}" /></li>
                            <li><b>Kalan: </b> <h:inputText readonly="true"
                                    value="#{accountBean.selectedCredit.remaining}" /></li>
                            <li><b>Durumu: </b> <h:outputText value="AKTİF" /></li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="twelve columns">
                        <p:dataTable var="ins" emptyMessage="Kayıt Bulunamadı..."
                            value="#{accountBean.selectedCredit.installations}"
                            id="credit_details_table">
                            <p:column headerText="Taksit No">
                                <h:outputText value="#{ins.installationNo}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="Vadesi">
                                <h:outputText value="#{ins.paymentDue}">
                                    <f:convertDateTime pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" />
                                </h:outputText>
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="Taksit Tutarı">
                                <h:outputText value="#{ins.amount}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="Taksit Tutarı">
                                <h:outputText value="#{ins.paidAmount}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="Ödeme Durumu">
                                <h:outputText value="#{ins.status}" />
                            </p:column>
                            <p:column headerText="Ödeme Tarihi">
                                <h:outputText value="#{ins.actualDate}" />
                            </p:column>
                        </p:dataTable>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </p:dialog>
        </h:form>
```

so what is the problem actually?

Comment: do you have thee same problem if your commandButton is not nested in a toolbar?

Comment: actually not tried, not suspected... let me try first, by the way it seems the actionListener is not being called at all at first time...

Comment: OK definitely the actionListener method is not being called at first time...why? I dunno. It's not related to toolbar...

Comment: Is the actionListener not called or just resolved to null? I think the problem could be that the actionListener is called first and selectedCredit is set afterwards. You can try to set selectedCredit manually by rowSelect-Event so it is set before you push the commandButton to recharge the Installation-List. Sorry for my bad english, I hope you got the main-idea ..

Comment: not resolved to null but it's not called. by the way, selectedCredit and load details are fine working on their lifecycle. After master page rendered, it contains the dialog ui as well (but set to null). When I click on the commandButton first time, nothings happens. If I click on the button second time, then it calls and everything else go smooth...

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, actionListener method must have signature: `public void actionListener(ActionEvent event)`. You could try using `action` instead of `actionListener`.

Also, do you have an enclosing form for your datatable? There was some bug in JSF when using multiple forms. Try to update the whole form instead of dialog only: `update=":productdetailform"`

Comment: this is not true. actionListener method works fine without ActionEvent  parameter.